# A UEFA Champions League/Europa League final between two teams who already played against one another in the group stage of either competition?

Tags: football, trivia, champions-league, europa-league

Has a UEFA Champions League/Europa League final took place between two teams who had already played against one another in the group stage of either competition?

Comment: Welcome to Sports Stack Exchange. Please write a complete question into the body; titles are only for reference and ease of finding questions in future.

Answer (score 4):

Europa League: No.

Champions League: Yes, twice.

- [1994/95](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1994%E2%80%9395_UEFA_Champions_League): Ajax - Milan (1-0)

  - Ajax won both games in the group stage 2-0
- [1998/99](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1998%E2%80%9399_UEFA_Champions_League): Manchester United - Bayern (2-1)

  - Both group stage games ended in a draw (2-2 and 1-1)